# https support for sites created with setwebcfg

Tags: google-cloud-storage

Currently I can create a static site from my bucket using

```
gsutil setwebcfg -m index.html -e 404.html gs://www.example.com
```

The site is then accessible through **http**://www.example.com
However the site is not accessible using **https**://www.example.com and I wonder whether that's possible and how to do it.

To note that the files themselves are accessible using **https**://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/www.example.com/index.html or **http**://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/www.example.com/index.html... but I'd like to have a better url.

To understand why, Some API like getUserMedia() requires user permission and https allows to have a persistent permission (otherwise the user has to give the permission every time)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, Google Cloud Storage does not support HTTPS connections to custom domains at this time.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. How can I make this a feature request (or know whether it is planned to be supported)?